# What loads (φορτία) does Jesus refers to when talking about them as heavy (βαρέα) and difficult to carry (δυσβάστακτα) in Mt 23:4?

Tags: matthew, law, pharisees, loads, traditions

What puzzles me in Mat 23:4

> They tie up heavy loads, hard to carry, and put them on men’s
> shoulders, but they themselves are not willing even to lift a finger
> to move them

is that, from what you can understand by reading the two preceding verses

> “The scribes and the Pharisees sit on Moses’ seat. Therefore pay
> attention to what they tell you and do it. But do not do what they do,
> for they do not practice what they teach

the basic teachings of the Pharisees were not wrong. The traditional and bad teachings, even though difficult and complicated (like exaggerated hand washing, fasting and kashrut observance, and strictness in keeping the Shabbath), were generally followed by the Pharisees themselves (not just told as commandments to be observed only by the others). Moreover, these complicated precepts could not surely be what Jesus had just told his disciples to learn from the Pharisee teachers (doing what they preached and not doing according to how they practiced what they preached).

Answer (score 2):

The NT appears to use the word "burden" φορτίον (phortion) is distinct ways:

- The load/burden of everyday living and life, eg, earning a living etc. Gal 6:5 This burden must be born by each person.
- The cargo load of a ship, Acts 27:10
- The load/burden of Jesus which is light, Matt 11:28, 30
- The load/burden of the pharisees in Matt 23:4 and Luke 11:46.

The OP's question only concerns this final load/burden.  Before answering the question, let us observe what Jesus said about this:

> Matt 23:3 - So you must be careful to do everything they tell you. But
> do not do what they do, for they do not practice what they preach.

Thus, it appears that Jesus may have been alluding to his remarks in Matt 15:3-6 after being asked about His disciples "breaking the tradition of the elders" (Matt 15:2)

> Jesus replied, “And why do you break the command of God for the sake
> of your tradition? For God said, ‘Honor your father and mother’ and
> ‘Anyone who curses his father or mother must be put to death.’ But you
> say that if anyone says to his father or mother, ‘Whatever you would
> have received from me is a gift devoted to God,’ he need not honor his
> father or mother with it. Thus you nullify the word of God for the
> sake of your tradition.

Thus, Jesus appears to be alluding to the multitude of extra-Biblical rules, invented by the pharisees ("the tradition of the elders") and others over time, that made the keeping of the law of burden instead of the blessing it was intended to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Burden of Pharisees** The Pharisee sect was a mixed lot! As Jesus noted:

(1) There were religious requirements they taught, but didn't keep themselves.

(2) There were complicated rituals they practiced that the average layman didn't have time or ability to do as well.

(3) There were loads (burdens) of teaching that only the extremely scholarly rabbis familiar with Hebrew syntax could understand or appreciate.

(4) There were Mosaic Laws that were correctly taught by the rabbis, that every one should obey.

In Jewish thought, the Teaching of the famous Rabbis was a "burden" which their disciples became "yoked to". Jesus announced that His *yoke was easy, and His **burden** was light*. (Matthew 11:28-30) This is why *the common people heard Him gladly;* His teaching was practical and positive, invigorating and inspirational! But the way the Rabbis taught the Mosaic Law was burdensome in many ways.

Paul warned that those Christian believers (Judaizers) who were leaving the simplicity of Jesus and returning back to the many details of the Mosaic Law, were returning to a **burden** (Galatians, chapters 3 and 4). In fact, Paul warned that they were teaching *another Gospel*, and in danger of being cursed. (Galatians 1:7-9)

In dealing with the influx of non-Jews (ethnics) into the Church, Peter declared that the Apostles *should lay upon them no greater **burden** than these necessary things.* (Acts 15:28) The few necessary things were:

- Abstain from meats offered unto idols
- Abstain from blood, and things strangled
- Abstain from fornication

Trying to obey the old Mosaic Law would be like placing a *yoke of bondage* upon themselves, instead of the light yoke of Christ. (Galatians 5:1) The Gentiles were to live holy and righteous lives, but their "righteousness was of Christ, imputed by His grace", and not from the arduous tasks of trying to keep the old Law."

For research on the teaching of the Jewish sects (Pharisees and Saducees, Herodians and Essenes), see Alfred Edershiem, **Life and Times of the Messiah**, and **Jewish Backgrounds to the New Testament**, J.Julius Scott.

Comment: Thank you. After reading the answers to my question given by Dottard and especially after reading this one given by Ray Grant, I would be prone to think that Jesus' reproach contained in verse 23:4 addresses - more than the human traditions introduced in the Law - the way and the motives of Pharisaic interpretation of Mosaic Law. In fact, against the spirit of Mich 6:8 (quoted by Jesus in verse 23:23), they were stressing what was more challenging to carry out, since they wanted to appear more s"spiritual" and were not even considering putting it into practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would tentatively answer my question suggesting that - even though the human traditions Jesus refers to in other passages (Mark 7:8-13, e.g.) were all selfishly favourable to the flesh - there may have also been precepts (possibly concerning chastity and private life in general) the Pharisees would teach (and impose as a heavy load to others - may be the younger or the converts) and not practise themselves.
In fact, in a few verses below (Mat 23:25), we read: “Woe to you, experts in the law and you Pharisees, hypocrites! You clean the outside of the cup and the dish, but inside, they are full of greed (γέμουσιν ἐξ ἁρπαγῆς) and self-indulgence (καὶ ἀκρασίας)." So Jesus here could be referring to things the Pharisees were telling others to be willing to give out or to be ready to refrain from.